# how to build a snap based on a jre

Tags: java, snap

I'm the developer of jape, a formal logic proof editor which uses java to provide a GUI and OCaml to provide a proof-step engine. (see rbornat/jape on github). I'm trying to package jape as a snap. The snap contains a jre, built using jlink and the JDK 11 from adoptopenjdk. It commences by calling a class in the jre.

To build the snap I had already to include `build-attributes: [keep-execstack]` because the JIT compiler (and another library, forgotten what) needs it.

The snap works with --devmode and --dangerous. I've told it to connect to `personal-files` so it can get at `~/.java`, and connected to `:home`. So far so good.

But the jre's garbage collector makes a *lot* of access to system files, shown to me by `snappy-debug`. For example, it starts with

```
= AppArmor =
Time: Aug 14 18:49:17
Log: apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.jape.jape" name="/proc/1/cgroup" pid=40869 comm="java" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
File: /proc/1/cgroup (read)
Suggestion:
* adjust program to not access '@{PROC}/@{pid}/cgroup'

= AppArmor =
Time: Aug 14 18:49:18
Log: apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.jape.jape" name="/proc/40869/coredump_filter" pid=40869 comm="java" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
File: /proc/40869/coredump_filter (write)
Suggestion:
* adjust program to not access '@{PROC}/@{pid}/coredump_filter'

= AppArmor =
Time: Aug 14 18:49:18
Log: apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="truncate" profile="snap.jape.jape" name="/proc/40869/coredump_filter" pid=40869 comm="java" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
File: /proc/40869/coredump_filter (write)
Suggestion:
* adjust program to not access '@{PROC}/@{pid}/coredump_filter'

= AppArmor =
Time: Aug 14 18:49:18
Log: apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.jape.jape" name="/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern" pid=40869 comm="java" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
File: /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern (read)
Suggestion:
* adjust program to not access '@{PROC}/sys/kernel/core_pattern'

= AppArmor =
Time: Aug 14 18:49:18
Log: apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.jape.jape" name="/proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid" pid=40869 comm="java" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
File: /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid (read)
Suggestion:
* adjust program to not access '@{PROC}/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid'

= AppArmor =
Time: Aug 14 18:49:18
Log: apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.jape.jape" name="/proc/1/cgroup" pid=40869 comm="java" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
File: /proc/1/cgroup (read)
Suggestion:
* adjust program to not access '@{PROC}/@{pid}/cgroup'
```

and later it spends lots of time reading stuff about memory

```
= AppArmor =
Time: Aug 14 18:49:18
Log: apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.jape.jape" name="/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/memory.limit_in_bytes" pid=40869 comm="java" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
File: /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/memory.limit_in_bytes (read)
Suggestions:
* adjust program to not access '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/memory.limit_in_bytes'
* adjust program to not access '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-[0-9]*.slice/user@[0-9]*.service/memory.limit_in_bytes'

= AppArmor =
Time: Aug 14 18:49:18
Log: apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="snap.jape.jape" name="/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/memory.usage_in_bytes" pid=40869 comm="java" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
File: /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/memory.usage_in_bytes (read)
Suggestions:
* adjust program to not access '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/memory.usage_in_bytes'
* adjust program to not access '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-[0-9]*.slice/user@[0-9]*.service/memory.usage_in_bytes'
```

I'm at a loss to see how to make this a snap. The `system-files` interface says the snap mustn't look at `/etc` or `/proc`; the `layout` mechanism doesn't like linking to `proc/1/cgroup` (which is all I've tried so far), and I would have to somehow provide *run-time* `uid` and `pid` values to describe what's going on. Yet the snapcraft documentation for java doesn't hint at any of these difficulties.

Help?

Comment: This seems like a good question for the Snapcraft experts at snap.io.